# Rspec test failing for POST member route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, factory-bot

I have a polymorphic vote model which POSTs through a member route on its parent models. Each parent has a "Vote" method in the controller and im trying to test this action in my controller tests. Please view the code below, for simplicity ill show one of the controller actions and test.

Regardless of my efforts and trying `id: @answer`, `id: @vote`, `FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:vote, user_id: @user2)` into the expect proc, I can't get this test to pass.

factoryGirl.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |u|
    u.sequence(:email) {|n| "test#{n}@hotmail.com"}
    u.sequence(:username) {|n| "tester#{n}" }
    u.password "password"
    u.password_confirmation "password" 
    u.remember_me true
    u.reputation 200
  end

factory :answer do
    user_id :user
    question_id :question
    body "you need to change your grip"
    votes_count 0
    correct true
  end

factory :vote do
    user_id :user
    votable_id :answer
    votable_type "Answer"
    value 1
  end
```

Answers_controller_spec.rb

```
describe "POST vote" do
    it "creates vote" do
      @user2 = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      @answer = FactoryGirl.create(:answer)
      @vote = FactoryGirl.create(:vote)
      expect {
        post :vote, id: @vote 
      }.to change(Vote, :count).by(1)
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
```

Test failure

```
Failures:

  1) AnswersController POST vote creates vote
     Failure/Error: expect {
       count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/controllers/answers_controller_spec.rb:90:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 2.01 seconds
9 examples, 1 failure
```

vote.rb

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :value, :votable_id, :votable_type
  belongs_to :votable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user

  validates_inclusion_of :value, in: [1, -1]
  validates_presence_of :user_id, :value, :votable_id, :votable_type, :points
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :votable_id
  validates_uniqueness_of :value, scope: :votable_id

  before_save :create_points

  def create_points
    self.value == 1 ? self.points = 5 : self.points = -3
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :answers do 
    member { post :vote }
    member { put :correct }
    resources :comments, except: [:edit, :update]
  end
```

answers_controller.rb

```
 def vote 
  @vote = current_user.votes.build(value: params[:value], votable_id: params[:id], votable_type: "Answer")
    respond_to do |format|
    if @vote.save
      format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: "Vote submitted" }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { redirect_to :back, alert: "You can't vote on your own content" }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` parameter is the id of the answer:

```
post :vote, id: @answer.id
```

You might also need to pass the `value` parameter (maybe an 'up' or 'down' value?).

There may be other reasons for the test to fail, e.g. validations in the `Vote` model. If `vote.save` returns false then check the `errors` collection.

Following comments:

You need to pass the `value` as a param to `post` in your spec. It also seems you have a duplicate vote, you probably don't need to create `@vote` in your spec at all. The `errors` collection is populated by the `valid?` method which is called by `save`.

Comment: i think its a validation problem, when commenting out the validations, the test passes, is there an issue with the FactoryGirl object?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the factories, if there is its probably in the answer factory (not shown). If I wanted to quickly work out what was going wrong here I would insert a `raise @vote.errors.inspect` (to quickly see the errors) or `binding.pry` (to debug) into the controller after the `else` and rerun the test.

Comment: I've added the answer factor to the original question.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the Answer factory either. What does `raise @vote.errors.inspect` tell you? Looking at the validations in `Vote` it is likely that one or more of the presence validations is failing. `create_points` should probably a `before_validation` callback not a `before_save` and you still need to pass that `value` param.

Comment: In dev the code works, and users can vote on anything with all of the  validations passing. So raising errors never gets called in the vote method. When commenting out the validations to see which ones are causing issues, its the top 3 which all cause the test to fail.

Comment: ok so you need to pass the `value` as a param to `post` in your spec. It also seems you have a duplicate `vote`, you probably don't need to create @vote in your spec at all. I was only suggesting that you raise errors in your controller as a temporary test. The `errors` collection is populated by the `valid?` method which is called by `save`.

Comment: Thanks Steve, amend your answer with your last comment and ill gladly accept it.